# How to print only certain conditions inside my for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

so I am trying to make a for loop to print a certain condition but it keeps printing all the conditions. How do I make it stop and print the outcome I want? Here's what I have done till now:

```
f_list = ['nothing','You will get an A', 'You will learn to program','You are destined to become a master coder','May the force be with you \n',
    'Wow. You look like a programmer','The code is strong with this one','You will be testing your code often','Taco cat spelled backwards is taco cat','Your name will go down, down, down in history \n',
    'You will master python']

for luckyInt in range(1 ,len(f_list)):
    if (luckyInt == 1):
        print(f_list[1])
    elif luckyInt == 2:
        print(f_list[2])
    elif luckyInt == 3:
        print(f_list[3])
    elif luckyInt == 4:
        print(f_list[4])
    elif luckyInt == 5:
        print(f_list[5])
    elif luckyInt == 6:
        print(f_list[6])
    elif luckyInt == 7:
        print(f_list[7])
    elif luckyInt == 8:
        print(f_list[8])
    elif luckyInt == 9:
        print(f_list[9])
    elif luckyInt == 10:
        print(f_list[10])
```

Hi: The required output is this:
Ooh-de-la-lay! Ooh-de-la-lay! Fortune tellers!
Fortunes forecast! Lucky charms!
Hmmm… the future is cloudy. What is your name?Leia Organa
Oo-dee-lally! How exciting! How many fortunes do you wish to get today?5
Your total for today’s session will be: 10.8455
I will tell your fortune. Leia Organa, enter your lucky integer number.300
Oops Leia Organa. I cannot tell your fortune until you enter a valid number.99
Leia Organa! This is your lucky day!
Your name will go down, down, down in history
I will tell your fortune. Leia Organa, enter your lucky integer number.-3
Oops Leia Organa. I cannot tell your fortune until you enter a valid number.3
Leia Organa! This is your lucky day!
You are destined to become a master coder
I will tell your fortune. Leia Organa, enter your lucky integer number.0
Leia Organa! This is your lucky day!
You will master python
I will tell your fortune. Leia Organa, enter your lucky integer number.-7
Oops Leia Organa. I cannot tell your fortune until you enter a valid number.7
Leia Organa! This is your lucky day!
You will be testing your code often
I will tell your fortune. Leia Organa, enter your lucky integer number.50000
Oops Leia Organa. I cannot tell your fortune until you enter a valid number.100
Leia Organa! This is your lucky day!
You will master python
You entered the following lucky numbers:
[99, 3, 0, 7, 100]
Process finished with exit code 0
:

Comment: Can you post your desired output of the code?

Comment: The code prints all elements of the list because every time **luckyInt** takes a value between 1 and len(f_list) it satisfies an __if__ condition. You might want to alter your __if__ condition to whatever you require.

Comment: try using the break statement inside the for loop under the condition you need to stop on

Comment: Your for loop runs N times and each time one condition will be True. So obviously it will print all the conditions

Comment: @Jonathan There is not stopping condition in the loop. Further If `luckyInt` become equal to `len(f_list)` in that case `print` statement will produce error (assuming if you have used similar print statement by seeing the pattern of conditionals). You need to provide a conditional statement for stopping the loop. Inside the conditional use `break` for  stopping the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I will print all because for each loop, it will enter a condition..
First loop will print 1, second will 2 and so on..
please provide the details with required output sample

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix your program and now it works great. It looks like you were close, but you need to give luckyInt a value and then compare that value to the index in a loop; rather than using luckInt as the index. I added a random number generator:

```
import random


def random_num(hi):
    lo = 0
    hi = hi-1
    return random.randint(lo, hi)


f_list = ['nothing', 'You will get an A', 'You will learn to program', 'You are 
destined to become a master coder \n',
'May the force be with you', 'Wow. You look like a programmer', 'The code is 
strong with this one \n',
'You will be testing your code often', 'Taco cat spelled backwards is taco cat \n',
'Your name will go down, down, down in history', 'You will master python']

luckyInt = random_num(len(f_list))

for i in range(len(f_list)):
    if luckyInt == i:
        print(f_list[i])
```

I hope this helps

Comment: In your example it looks like the user will input the luckyInt value, so you don't need the random number generator you can just use luckyInt = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

Comment: Hi, so it's still not printing the fortune out and there's no errors or anything what should I do?

Comment: What is it printing for you? This prints the phrase that corresponds to the index value equal to luckyInt for me.